# Diagnosing MemoryError for single-machine out-of-core computation using dask

Tags: dask

I am trying out dask for a POC of single-node out-of-core computation. 
My full script is below.

I am running dask 0.18.1 under (Anaconda) Python 3.6.5 on an AWS 2 vCPU, machine on Ubuntu v16 - 64bit, with 4GB of RAM and 16GB of SSD. The size of the RAM is intentional as I want to see intermediate results being spilled to disk and not having everything being completely in memory all the time.

My input data is not that big (around 300 MB) It can be gotten from here:
[Gowalla - checkins](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/loc-gowalla_totalCheckins.txt.gz). It contains a log of user checkins to a bunch of location (it includes user_id, location_id, checkin_timestamp).  The computation I am trying to run generates an intermediate result that is a lot bigger than the input data. This happens because, for each location, we generate  the set of all distinct pairs of users (a,b) that have visited with the check-in time of a being < the check-in time of b.

My script takes a single argument that determines what fraction of the input data to use for the experiment.

Thus when running it as:

```
python dask_experiment.py 10
```

It subsets 10% of the records at the beginning and goes from there.
The output in this is as follows:

```
Running on 10% of data
Time elapsed connecting to file and defining chins5 : 0.071 s
Time elapsed computing size of initial dataset : 20.576 s
len(chins1) = 642383

Time elapsed computing q999 : 34.751 s
Time elapsed computing chins5 : 34.918 s

          user_id_x  user_id_y  location_count
1436385      10971      10971              44
293388        1404       1080              40
...
```

So everything is hunky-dory in this case.

When running it as:

```
python dask_experiment.py 50
```

I get the following

```
Running on 50% of data 
Time elapsed connecting to file and defining chins5 : 0.069 s 
Time elapsed computing size of initial dataset : 20.635 s 
len(chins1) = 3238246

Killed   # :.( !
```

The experiment above is the default configuration.

```
{'array': {'chunk-size': '128MiB', 'rechunk-threshold': 4},
 'distributed': {'admin': {'log-format': '%(name)s - %(levelname)s - '
                                         '%(message)s',
                           'log-length': 10000,
                           'pdb-on-err': False,
                           'tick': {'interval': '20ms', 'limit': '3s'}},
                 'client': {'heartbeat': '5s'},
                 'comm': {'compression': 'auto',
                          'default-scheme': 'tcp',
                          'recent-messages-log-length': 0,
                          'socket-backlog': 2048,
                          'timeouts': {'connect': '10s', 'tcp': '30s'}},
                 'dashboard': {'export-tool': False,
                               'link': 'http://{host}:{port}/status'},
                 'scheduler': {'allowed-failures': 3,
                               'bandwidth': 100000000,
                               'default-data-size': 1000,
                               'transition-log-length': 100000,
                               'work-stealing': True,
                               'worker-ttl': None},
                 'version': 2,
                 'worker': {'memory': {'pause': 0.8,
                                       'spill': 0.7,
                                       'target': 0.6,
                                       'terminate': 0.95},
                            'multiprocessing-method': 'forkserver',
                            'profile': {'cycle': '1000ms', 'interval': '10ms'},
                            'use-file-locking': True}}}
```

I tried fiddling with the `worker.memory.*` parameters, to try to force spilling to disk sooner, but got what seems like worse error.

```
Running on 50 % of data
Time elapsed connecting to file and defining chins5 : 0.071 s
Time elapsed computing size of initial dataset : 20.361 s
len(chins1) = 3238246

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dask_experiment.py", line 79, in <module>
    main()
  File "dask_experiment.py", line 61, in main
    q999   = easy_time_it( lambda : q999.compute(), "computing q999" )
  File "dask_experiment.py", line 72, in easy_time_it
    result = fun()
  File "dask_experiment.py", line 61, in <lambda>
    q999   = easy_time_it( lambda : q999.compute(), "computing q999" )
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 156, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 402, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/threaded.py", line 75, in get
    pack_exception=pack_exception, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 521, in get_async
    raise_exception(exc, tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/compatibility.py", line 69, in reraise
    raise exc
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 290, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 271, in _execute_task
    return func(*args2)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/methods.py", line 355, in merge
    suffixes=suffixes, indicator=indicator)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 62, in merge
    return op.get_result()
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 582, in get_result
    concat_axis=0, copy=self.copy)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 5421, in concatenate_block_managers
    concatenate_join_units(join_units, concat_axis, copy=copy),
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 5575, in concatenate_join_units
    concat_values = concat_values.copy()
MemoryError
```

I wonder whether this situation could be fixed somehow...

**Can anybody give me some suggestions on what to try?**

My code below

```
import os, sys, time, pprint, dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.distributed #even though not explicitely used it sets up some config options as side effect...


def load_define( data_dir, subset_fun ) :
    #checkins_df = dd.read_hdf( data_dir + 'gowalla_checkins.hdf5', key='data' )
    checkins_df_0 = dd.read_csv( data_dir +  'loc-gowalla_totalCheckins.txt',
                                 delimiter="\t", names=['user_id', 'checkin_ts', 'lat', 'lon', 'location_id'],
                                 parse_dates = ["checkin_ts"] )

    chins1 = subset_fun( checkins_df_0[["user_id", "location_id", "checkin_ts"]] )

    chins2 = chins1.merge( chins1, on="location_id" )
    chins3 = chins2[ chins2.checkin_ts_x < chins2.checkin_ts_y ]

    chins4 = ( chins3[["user_id_x", "user_id_y", "location_id"]]
                     .drop_duplicates()
                     .groupby(["user_id_x", "user_id_y"])
                     .agg( {"location_id" : "count"})
                     .rename( columns = { "location_id" : "location_count" } )
                     .reset_index() )

    q999 = chins4['location_count'].quantile( 0.999 )

    chins5 = chins4[ chins4.location_count > q999 ]

    return chins1, chins4, q999, chins5


def main( ) :
    #%%
    if os.name == 'nt' :
        data_dir = "C:/_DATA/experimentation/"
    else :
        data_dir = "./"
        #%%
    pprint.pprint( dask.config.config )

    pct_of_input_data = float(sys.argv[1])
    print( "Running on %.0f%% of data" % pct_of_input_data )

    subset_fun = lambda dd0 : subset( dd0, 100, pct_of_input_data  )

    ( chins1,
      chins4,
      q999,
      chins5 ) = easy_time_it( lambda : load_define(data_dir, subset_fun),
                               "connecting to file and defining chins5" )
    size1 = easy_time_it( lambda : len(chins1), "computing size of initial dataset" )
    print( "len(chins1) = %d\n" % size1 )
    q999   = easy_time_it( lambda : q999.compute(), "computing q999" )
    chins5 = easy_time_it( lambda : chins5.compute(), "computing chins5" )

    print( "\n", chins5.sort_values('location_count', ascending=False).head() )


def subset( dd0, mod, h ) :
    return dd0[ dd0.location_id % mod < h ]

def easy_time_it( fun, msg = "" ) :
    t0 = time.clock()
    result = fun()
    t1 = time.clock( )
    print( "Time elapsed " + msg  +  " : %.3f s" % (t1 - t0) )
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

Comment: This is very long code and hard for us to replicate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If you really want to replicate, the code is designed to be self-contained. Just copy it completely, download the second .txt file from here https://snap.stanford.edu/data/loc-gowalla.html  (the total_Checkins one, its about 100 MB compressed)  uncompress it and run the script above  with  python script.py 100. I will rename the the file in the code so that you don't even have to do that. Alternatively just run the lines inside the load_define and then compute() on the final DataFrame.

Comment: In any case, I was mostly looking for suggestions on how to tune my config, or pointers on documentation on that, because I have found it a bit scarce.  I really want to give Dask a chance, because I think it's really cool and has a lot more features and potential than alternatives such as turicreate. For this particular problem, turicreate does just fine, out of the box with no config. That's why I thought I would have no problem getting dask to work. For other more interesting problems, turicreate will probably not cut it...